# Monitor saying "No video input", computer turns on however

Tags: memory, troubleshooting

I really need help with this problem. Here's a detailed description of it:

When I press the power button, the computer fires up with all the fans spinning and all the lights turning on. It'll suddenly shut down for a few seconds, but then start again. However, the monitor doesn't get any signal, therefore giving the "No video input" and going into sleep mode. I've seemed to figure out that the problem isn't in the monitor but the computer, as when I try to toggle CAPS lock on the keyboard connected, it won't work. In fact, the keyboard and mouse don't seem to work at all. I've tried to disconnect all cables, hold the power button for 1 min., and the try but that didn't work. I've also tried taking the RAM out and just clicking it back in.

Comment: Are there any beeps from the motherboard when it powers up? What is the make and model of your computer?

Comment: No, there aren't any beeps. The PC is custom-built, so I'm not sure. It's an ASUS pc, but that's all I know